# How to generate markdown documentation from c++ project?

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I am trying to create a documentation for a complex c++ project.

To do so, i started using Doxygen, which is appropriate for my usage because i just have to comment the headers of my project to get a full documentation in HTML. This documentation in is perfectly working and has a good style.

But here is my problem I want to get this documentation in a Markdown file to be able to push it on Gitlab.

I tried to use moxygen to convert the xml files to a md file. It works but not as properly as I want: the anchors generated automatically by moxygen are not working. The presentation is also a problem for example it puts the definition list on the top of the file which is very long and not the most useful in the documentation.

I would like to know then if there is a way to document my code as simply as using Doxygen but getting a proper markdown file ( anchors working and better template) .

I know the markdown syntax is simple but i can't write the whole markdown by myself because the project is big and is going to be updated often so i need a generic method to get documentation in markdown from a C++ project.

Comment: This is not a C++ question. Please remove the tag.

Comment: Secondly, this is basically a question asking for documentation/tutorial. This is off-topic here on SO. Please read [help/on-topic].

Comment: Why not push the resulting HTML to gitlab or a pdf from the resulting LaTeX output or docbook or ...?  In case of the conversion from xml to markdown I think you should contact the developers of moxygen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I can't push it as a PDF because i am working in a company and our documentation needs to be directly usable from gitlab like markdown which is integrated to gitlab. Pushing it as a HTML could be a good solution but I dont know yet how to push it and link it simply, I will investigate on this. The best solution would have been to get a proper markdown file.

Comment: So you want an HTML-to-Markdown conversion tool. Unfortunately, they are rare and with a couple exceptions, they tend to be incomplete. Regardless, tool recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will pay more attention to the help center before posting next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem some time ago, and it was not easy to solve. Basically what I did is to convert the documentation to LaTeX, and from there, to markdown. Check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341899/latex-to-markdown-converter) to the LaTeX->Markdown passage (other tools existe as well).

You can automate the process using make/latexmke to some point, but I personally have not been able to make the process easy and I still need to step in sometimes. Also note that you might need to use other tools, like flex, to make your LaTeX document into one big `tex` file. Some conversion programs do not accept split `tex` files.

This is not perfect, but it might give you another angle at this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already read about this tool to convert my Latex to HTML but I did'nt know there was a way to gather all the tex files into a big one so i gave up that idea. But seeing from that angle it looks better I will try this next time I document.

The solution I used was writting the documentation on the include files for Doxygen. Then get a XML documentation, convert it to Markdown, and at the end correct manually the anchors problems and presentation by editing the Md file produced. It was the best solution I found untilll your message but it's still quite long.

Comment: Yes, see section 3.1 [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents#Produce_a_single_.tex_from_modular_documents) for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Markdown support was introduced in [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html) version 1.8.0.

Comment: The question of the markdown support is about markdown output, the markdown support you refer to is about markdown input, so your answer in no answers the question.